# Is there a mySQL equivalent to Postgresql's "Dollar-Quoted String Constants"?

Tags: mysql

In postgresql, it's possible to use "Dollar-Quoted String Constants" to avoid escaping single quotes in constant strings:

Without Dollar-Quoted String Constants:

```
'Jeff''s table'
```

With Dollar-Quoted String Constants:

```
$$Jeff's table$$
```

Is there a MySQL equivalent?

On edit: I'm not looking for a way to sanitize inputs, I'm looking for a way to make queries that generate sql easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

No, because it doesn't really work.  An attacker just addes a pair of dollar signs to their injection attempt instead.

The correct way to handle this is a system that uses real query parameters, such that the parameter values are *never* substituted directly into a query string.  This is also generally better for performance because the db can do a better job caching the execution plan you don't end up building string dynamically, which tends to be slow in modern languages.

Not having excess concatenation statements greatly improves the readability of the code, as well.  Instead of this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column1=$$" + somevarialbe + "$$ AND Column2=$$" + OtherVariable";
```

it's just this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable wHERE Column1=@Value1 AND Column2=@Value2";
```

---

Hmm... Okay, I can see some limited utility for this feature now.

Imagine a ticket tracking system with a stored procedure to get open tickets.  You might actually hard-code the literal 'open' into the where clause of the query.  Not that this would be a good design — ticket status should be in a table with it's own key, so that you'd hardcode the key rather than the text.  But it plants the seed for something valid and more-complicated.

Comment: Not that I recommend this over using query parameters, but in Postgres the two dollar signs can contain an arbitrary text between them which must then close the sequence. So you could do something like `sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE column = $secretKey$" + someVariable + "$secretKey$";` and you'd be fine as long as an attacker doesn't guess the `secretKey`. You could even randomize it for every query :)

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose your string in double quotes instead, e.g.

```
"Jeff's table"
```

Note: If this doesn't work, it means that you've got `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode turned on. The [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html) say:

> If the `ANSI_QUOTES` SQL mode is enabled, string literals can be quoted only within single quotation marks because a string quoted within double quotation marks is interpreted as an identifier.